# Codeigniter pagination is not work in Linux machine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have develop a project on codeigniter. On xamp server.The pagination is working fine on that project on xamp server but when I shift the same project in to my linux server then the whole project work but the pagination is not working.

Can anybody give me any solution on that issue? why the same code pagination is not working on linux server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying the same source code in different PHP versions with different settings, it's not likely that pagination is failing because of the operating system PHP runs on.

I suggest you enable full error reporting in both servers. That will give you a clue about what's wrong.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks,but everything is working fine except the pagination functionality.both xamp and my linux server use same php version.So ,any other way?its

Comment: Not a single notice in E_ALL mode? What does "does not work" mean for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing $config['uri_protocol'] around in application/config/config.php.

I'll put a shiny penny on "REQUEST_URI" fixing this.

Comment: What? Why is this -1? One of the most common problems with URI routing is the URI protocol. Try each one of the values in turn and you will find more often than not one will make it work. Normally, that is REQUEST_URI.

What a dick.